# Incorrect base URL for Backbone DELETE requests - uses relative instead of absolute URLs

Tags: django, backbone.js, cordova, tastypie

TL;DR version:

Building a Phonegap app using Backbone, and have a model called Client and a collection called Clients. Using a Tastypie API to communicate with a separate server. When I run `fetch()`, the URL uses the correct absolute URL (something like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/client/1/`, but when I run `Client.destroy()`, it uses a relative URL of `file:///api/v1/client/1/`. How can I make it use the absolute URL for deleting the object?

Long version:

I'm building a mobile app with Backbone.js that consumes a Django/Tastypie API, and I've run into some seemingly odd behaviour that I can't figure out.

I define a base URL for the server at the top of the file:

```
// Set the base URL for querying the API
baseUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/';
```

I have the following model and collection:

```
// Client model
Client = Backbone.Model.extend({

    urlRoot: baseUrl + 'client',

    // Default values
    defaults: {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        mobile: '',
        email: '',
        notes: '',
        operator: '',
        date_client_joined: '',
        address: '',
        postcode: ''
    }
});

// Client collection
Clients = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    // Will hold Client objects
    model: Client,

    // Set URL
    url: baseUrl + 'client/'
});
```

And the individual clients are rendered in a list using the following view:

```
// Client list item view
ClientListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',

    events: {
        'click .delete': 'deleteclient'
    },

    render: function () {
        // Render the client list item template
        var template = _.template($('#client-list-item-template').html());
        this.$el.html(template(this.model.toJSON()));

        // Return the object
        return this;
    },

    deleteclient: function () {
        this.model.destroy();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Now, the app actually uses jQuery Mobile and each client has a Delete button next to it with a class of delete, so the deleteclient function is executed each time one of these buttons is clicked. I'm also using backbone-tastypie to iron out the inconsistencies between Backbone and Tastypie.

The deleteclient function is running, but it sends the HTTP DELETE request to a relative URL of `file:///api/v1/client/1/` (as this is a Phonegap app, I'm just viewing the files locally). From the documentation setting urlRoot manually seems like the way to go, but doing so didn't seem to solve the issue. Running the fetch() function to populate the collection works absolutely fine, though - it uses the correct absolute URL.

So, my question is how can I override the default behaviour and ensure my HTTP DELETE request is sent to the correct URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at your code it should work ok. The Model in backbone already has a `url()` function defined which should do this:

```
url: function() {
  var base = _.result(this, 'urlRoot') || _.result(this.collection, 'url') || urlError();
  if (this.isNew()) return base;
  return base + (base.charAt(base.length - 1) === '/' ? '' : '/') + encodeURIComponent(this.id);
},
```

Can you use the debugger to see if it enters inside this code and what is the result of it? Mainly check the values from the `_.result()` calls...

Anyway, you can override the `url` property in your models rather than passing it in every call to `destroy()`:

```
Client = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: function () { return baseUrl + 'client/' + this.id + '/'; }
    // other code...
});
```

Comment: The `url()` method wasn't being called for some reason. However, overriding it works OK so I'll go with that.

Comment: Maybe you want to check the backbone version you are using... happy that everything is working anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, though I'm not entirely happy with it:

```
    deleteclient: function () { 
        if (confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this client?')) {
            // Destroy the model
            this.model.destroy({
                url: baseUrl + 'client/' + this.model.get('id') + '/'
            });  

            // Remove the view
            this.remove();
        }    
    }
```

Basically, if I explicitly pass through the URL to destroy(), that does the trick. It's a little annoying that I can't find a more DRY way to do this, so I'm open to any other method of doing the same thing.